How to prevent ImageView from being clipped at the edges of a LinearLayout in Android?
I am trying to make a profile image to be placed on top of the border, but it keeps getting cropped out by the borders of the linear layout.
Here is my code:
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/home_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:src="@drawable/jett_mccandless"
            app:civ_border_color="#70757d"
            app:civ_border_width="3dp" />

I tried putting the image inside a frame layout and turned off clipChildren and clipToPadding, but the linear layout keeps cutting it off.

Please, post the complete xml code

The problem in your code is that you have set the height of CircleImageView to 70dp, but the height of its parent (Linear Layout) is 60dp. That's why the image view is being clipped at the edges of Linear Layout. So, even after turning off clipToPadding and clipChildren, the image view is being clipped.
Either change height of Linear Layout to 70dp or change height of CircleImageView to 60dp according to your needs.
Hope this helps.
